# couldnot use jdbc driver for java servlet using apache server v7.0 to connect mysql 5.5 and even 5.1.22

Tags: mysql, apache, jdbc

I am trying to use jdbc driver for mysql. But driver is not found and gives the following error in eclipse.(I am using Tomcat v7.0 at localhost)

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/mydata[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@50aaaf66
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at AddStudent.doPost(AddStudent.java:52)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have Searched Documentation around and got this..

> In general, follow the installation instructions that come with your
>   version of Tomcat, as the way you configure datasources in Tomcat
>   changes from time to time, and if you use the wrong syntax in your XML
>   file, you will most likely end up with an exception similar to the
>   following:
>
> **Error: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'null ' SQL state: null**
>
> Note that the auto-loading of drivers having the
>   META-INF/service/java.sql.Driverclass in JDBC 4.0 causes an improper
>   undeployment of the Connector/J driver in Tomcat on Windows. Namely,
>   the Connector/J jar remains locked. This is an initialization problem
>   that is not related to the driver. The possible workarounds, if
>   viable, are as follows: use **"antiResourceLocking=true"** as a Tomcat
>   Context attribute, or **remove the META-INF/directory.**

Documentation recommended not to use **antiResourceLocking**.
I couldnot understand the other one..
is there any other method to solve this problem or recommend me of any of the above process.
Since I am new to web could you please help with detail in your suggestion.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your `doPost` method?  I'm concerned about the `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/mydata[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@50aaaf66` bit: I don't know how you've managed to add an array of `StackTraceElement`s to your connection string.  Also, do you have the MySQL connector JAR in your web app's `lib` folder?

Comment: that part is due to this line in catch block
System.out.println(sqle.getStackTrace());
Sorry that I pasted that too..

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialized/loaded up the driver with something like:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

before calling DriveManager.getConnection(...)